# View Z depth vs depth in preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, depth-map

My rendered *view z depth* does not match the *depth in the viewport* and I'm wondering why / if there is an explanation for this.

I've a super-simple scene: Just, a camera looking at a flat plane, parallel to the camera. When viewing this scene in the 3D viewport, I clearlry see that the plane and the camera are seperated by 5Blender Units in Z.

I'm using the *camera data node*'s *view z depth* to render the depth via cycles and saving the result in openxr files in order to not loose any precision. This actually works out quite nicely. However, for some reason the exported depth is 2.5 Blender Units, I've to multiply all my z depths by two.

I can do that, no problem, but I would be curious why this is the case. Do you have an idea wy this is sthe case?

EDIT:

- Measure the distances between the camera and the plane in the viewport and get a depth of 5 Blender Units. 
  [image: viewport measurement]
  (Yes, I'm 0.001810 off, but just because I did not click very accurartly while measuring. I know that the plane and the camera have distance of 5 Blender Units in Z from the coordinates...)
- I output the z depth via shading node. Note that I have to multiply the depth by two.
  [image: zdepth]
- ONLY IF I multiply the z depth by two the depth output matches the measurement done in the viewport. 
  [image: Output]

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce it, it seems to work fine for me. When I "color pick" a pixel of the render or of the exported exr, it shows me RGB = 5,5,5. Could you please provide your .blend ?

Comment: Also, is there any reason you don't use a Z Depth pass instead ?

Comment: How do you inspect the pixels values? No issues when using the image editor... (Z is ~5 when picking the pixels of the plane vs infinity)

Comment: I export the z depth using the OpenEXR image format, which I can open using the banterle HDR toolbox in MATLAB.

Comment: Seems incorrect over there. @Nici